# Sequelize – query include with belongsToMany or hasMany

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have `User` and `Deal` models. They are associated with `belongsToMany` relationship through `UserDeals`.

Let's say I have a deal like this:

```
const deal = {
  id: 'my-id',
  users: [{ id: 'user-a' }, { id: 'user-b' }]
};
```

How can I find it without having its `id` but having both users' ids?

Comment: You can try to query UserDeals and add `include` Deal and User models, `where` clause  and `required: true` in User `include`